# Uri for accesing to a specific document in OneDrive

Tags: c#, onedrive, universal

In the code below from an Universal App( windows 10), Skype can be opened and the *usertocall* will be called.
If this uri is changed for ***new Uri(@"ms-Onedrive:");*** OneDrive App will be opened.
Which is the right Uri for getting access to an specific document stored in the Onedrive ?

```
 private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uriSkype = new Uri(@"skype:(usertocall)?call");

        // Set the option to show a warning
        var promptOptions = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
     //   promptOptions.TreatAsUntrusted = true;

        // Launch the URI
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriSkype);

        if (success)
        {
            // URI launched
        }
        else
        {
            // URI launch failed
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the local protocol handler to access files. It is used for communicating between apps and asking the OneDrive app to display various UI, but won't let you access files.

You need to use the OneDrive API (https://dev.onedrive.com) to have access to a user's OneDrive content.

Comment: In fact I am calling  OneDrive App from other UniversalApp running in the same device (Hololens)